# Send file from PC to Android via Socket

Tags: android, delphi, sockets

I have two problems with sending files on the computer from android
the first problem, use the following code to send

```java
Socket sock;
try {
    sock = new Socket("172.16.3.120", 1025); 
    System.out.println("Connecting...");

    // sendfile
    File myFile = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/UchTeh/uchteh.db"); 
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("Sending...");
    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();

    sock.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

file on your computer accept delphi

```
procedure TServerRcvThread.ClientExecute;
var
  SockStream : TWinSocketStream;
  FileInfo   : TFileInfo;
  FileStream : TFileStream;
  RcvBuf     : array[0..140] of Byte;
  nRead      : Integer;
  nToRead    : Integer;
  nTotal     : Integer;
begin
  FStatus := 'Unknown error';
  SockStream := TWinSocketStream.Create( ClientSocket, 10000 );
  try
    if SockStream.WaitForData(10000) then begin
      nRead := SockStream.Read( FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo) );
      if (nRead = SizeOf(FileInfo)) then  begin
        nTotal := 0;
        FileStream := TFileStream.Create( FDir + '\' + FileInfo.FileName, fmCreate );
        try
          while(nTotal < FileInfo.FileLength) do begin
            nToRead := (FileInfo.FileLength - nTotal);
            if (nToRead > SizeOf(RcvBuf)) then
              nToRead := SizeOf(RcvBuf);
            nRead := SockStream.Read( RcvBuf, nToRead );
            if (nRead = 0) then Exit;
            nTotal := nTotal + nRead;
            FileStream.Write( RcvBuf, nRead );
          end;
        finally
          FileStream.Free;
        end;
        if (nTotal = FileInfo.FileLength) then
          FStatus := 'File ' + FileInfo.FileName + ' received ('
                   + IntToStr(nTotal) + ' bytes)'
        else
          FStatus := 'File ' + FileInfo.FileName + ' error ('
                  + IntToStr(nTotal) + ' bytes)';
      end
      else
        FStatus := 'File info header error';
    end
    else begin
      FStatus := 'Client delay error';
      ClientSocket.Close;
      Terminate;
    end;
  finally
    SockStream.Free;
    Synchronize( SetStatus );
  end;
end;
```

file size to send and receive various
please help me, I myself will not understand the problem in its

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android code is sending just the raw file contents by itself and nothing else, but the Delphi code is expecting to receive a `TFileInfo` record first followed by the file data. So your Delphi code is not going to work until the source file itself contains an accurate `TFileInfo` at the start of its raw data.  Does it?

You are also not taking endian into account when reading the `TFileInfo.FileLength`, if it is a multi-byte integer (you did not show what `TFileInfo` is defined as).  You have to make sure multi-byte integer values are in the same endian that Delphi expects.  I don't know what endian Android uses for multi-byte integer values.  Most network protocols are standardized on Network Byte Order when transmitting mult-byte integers, so you should adopt the same convention in your protocol.

If the file really does contain a `TFileInfo` record, then read it from the file first, swap the endian of its integer fields as needed, transmit it, then finish transmitting the rest of the file data.  Otherwise, you need to create and send an appropriate `TFileInfo` before then sending the complete file data.

On the Delphi side, you can then read the `TFileInfo` (regardless of where it originated from), swap the endian of its integer fields as needed, then finish reading the rest of the file data.

If, after all of that, you are still having problems, then you need to update your question with more specific details about what exactly is going wrong with your code (error messages, unexpected symptoms, etc), what data is actually in the source file, etc.